# Question that has already been asked

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am pretty new to StackOverflow. Hence I don't understand all of the nitty-gritty details of the community.

Let's say I have a question, and on searching on StackOverflow, I find that it has already been asked and answered, however, when I try the answer, I find a different error.

How should I proceed about this? Should I ask a new question altogether and reference the question that has already been asked? Should I comment on the answer provided, though my error is a couple of lines long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should ask a new question, reference the original one and state in detail how the answers on the referenced question didn't work for you.

Show what you have tried to solve the problem and how it failed.